# Cannot Download TensorFlow Quantum

Tags: programming, tfq

Hey Quantum Computing community,

I cannot get TensorFlow Quantum to work even though I am using

`pip install tensorflow-quantum`

I have TensorFlow already on Visual Studio Code, and I know it is a prerequisite for being able to download TensorFlow Quantum. I even tried going down a level of TensorFlow (I think it is called downgrading), but unfortunately, my Visual Studio Code terminal does not recognize it.

Thank You!

Update: Including image down below:[image: What I tried doing]

Comment: You need to include more information about the error that's occurring. What does it say is going wrong?

Comment: If you continue to have trouble, TFQ is available as a pre-configured environment on qBraid, see https://youtu.be/iqYmB7H2R2E

Comment: @CraigGidney please refer to my image attached while I updated my original question.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're on a windows machine. Based on the files present on pypi ( https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-quantum/0.7.2/#files ), there's only linux and osx distributions of the wheel.

I think this means you'll have to use it [via collab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/quantum/blob/master/docs/tutorials/hello_many_worlds.ipynb), or switch to a non-windows computer.

Comment: The [Windows subsystem for linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) is also an option.